# creating background Android process using HTML5 API

Tags: android, html

Just wondering if is there a way to create background task in Android using HTML5 API instead of using native Java SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. The closest thing HTML5 has to that is the "Web worker" concept, and Android does not support that as of Android 2.2 AFIAK. Even that does not really qualify as "background task" to my way of thinking.